# How to make a fetch variable JSON readable and then parse values

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am using the nutritionix API for a project and I need to get the value that is returned as result. Below is the relevant portion of the code, and the function section inside is an async function.

```
let result = fetch("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => {return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));})
        .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error))
    
    console.log(await result)
    console.log('foods: ', await result.foods)
```

The result when console logged is something along the lines of.

```
{
    "foods": [
        {
            "food_name": "rice cake",
            "brand_name": null,
            "serving_qty": 1,
            "serving_unit": "cake",
            "serving_weight_grams": 9,
            "nf_calories": 34.83,
            ...
```

So I am trying to make a JSON string so that I can go through and read calories for each food that is listed in foods. But when I read `result.foods` it comes back as undefined.

Comment: Because you run `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` instead of just doing `.then(response => response.json())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     .then(response => response.text())
>     .then(result => {return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));})
> ```

1. `result` is a string (text)
2. `JSON.stringify` converts that to a string containing JSON representation of that string
3. `JSON.parse` (the opposite of `JSON.stringify`) converts that back to the original string

You therefore have a string, which doesn't have a `foods` property.

---

If you were (and you *shouldn't*) to use this general approach, you should not stringify the data first.

```
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => {return JSON.parse(result);})
```

---

That's a poor choice however since response objects have built-in support for parsing JSON:

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: That worked thank you, I didn't realize that was the issue.